# IOS - Remove Uilabel from two different views of app at a time

Tags: ios, iphone, uilabel

I have created an `UILabel` in First view and added it to Second view and Third View. Now as I open the Fourth View then the `UILabel` added on Second and Third View should be removed.

```
-(void)initializeMarqueeLabelWithViewController:(UIViewController *)viewCont {
```

> Label created on First View and added on Second and Third View

```
rightLeftLabel = [[MarqueeLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 483, viewCont.view.frame.size.width-20, 20) rate:50.0f andFadeLength:10.0f];
rightLeftLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
rightLeftLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
rightLeftLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
rightLeftLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-BOLD" size:15.000];
rightLeftLabel.marqueeType = MLContinuous;
[UIColor whiteColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,6)];
[rightLeftLabel setAttributedText: string];
[viewCont.view addSubview:rightLeftLabel];
}
```

> Removed when Fourth View is Opened

```
[rightLeftLabel removeFromSuperview];
```

> But it is removing it from one view only Second or Third

Comment: Can you show some more code, how you are adding and removing the label? (method and flow)

Comment: initializing this label 
[APP_DELEGATE initializeMarqueeLabelWithViewController:self];

Comment: This method is initialized for e.g on Second View on which i want this label same for Third View also. Now i want to remove this label from both the views

Answer (score 0):

You can give some tag to your label and while removing use viewWithTag: to get that view and remove it from superview.

```
rightLeftLabel = [[MarqueeLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 483, viewCont.view.frame.size.width-20, 20) rate:50.0f andFadeLength:10.0f];
rightLeftLabel.tag = 1001; // orany other tag
```

while removing,

```
  UIView *view = [secondView viewWithTag:1001]; 
  [view removeFromSuperView];

  view = [thirdView viewWithTag:1001]; 
  [view removeFromSuperView];
```

Comment: I tried this UIView *view = [secondView viewWithTag:1001];  
I am getting nil here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check address of "rightLeftLabel"? I think it's creating new.

Otherwise it should remove with same memory address.

Comment: ya at same time i am creating two rightLeftLabel for two views with one method... but it is removing only one rightLeftLabel

Comment: It mean you need to take two variable one for left label and other for right label. Currently you are taking single variable and it storing last label address and removing last label.

Comment: some how you said is right but here i want to show this UILabel in both the Views thats why i am initializing this UILabel in that both Views but during removing it it is removing the last label that i have created .